# How we can use loglevel-management by using Spring Boot Admin?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Currently i am using logback for logging purpose , i just heard about spring boot admin but does not get an exact idea about how to implement loglevel-management by using Spring Boot Admin , please any one tell me how we can implement this .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to expose your application by JMX bean using **jolokia** [details](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.3/#jmx-bean-management)
2. You can access log level management via JMX bean using spring boot admin client [details](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.3/#loglevel-management)

Comment: only applies to spring boot admin 1.4.x and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using spring boot admin 1.5.x and spring boot 1.5.x on your client you don't need to do anything - it should just work.